# Filling object inside Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Im start to learn about TPL and now have question.
I have class Worker which start Task inside constructor. I sync these task with manual reset event. But I want to get some statistics about this. So I tried to fill object inside this Task. Is this good idea?

```
 public Worker(...)
    {
       ...
        StatisticItem = new StatisticItem();
      ....

        Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           //Manual reset event
            WaitForSignalToStart.WaitOne();
            while (source.IsMyTurn(RepeatOrder))
            {
                Item item;
                var realTimeWatch = new Stopwatch();
                while (TryGetNext(out item))
                {
                   ...
                    DoWork()
                    StatisticItem.PlanItemId =...
                    StatisticItem.CommandAndQueryName =...
                    StatisticItem.WokrerId = ...
                    StatisticItem.ThreadId = ...
                    StatisticItem.Date = ...

                 }
        }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have one Task who access this specific `StatisticItem`, you should be fine. This works because lamba statements are able to use variables from the context they are created in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but if the `StatisticItem` is a field, you can only have one Task active. Also it's advisable to Lock the `StatisticItem`

Comment: StatisticItem is property with private set. So it needs lock or no?

Comment: The instance of the statisticsitem isn't the problem. It about the properties of the StatisticsItem you're about to read and write. You need to use to lock any object as long the same object instance is used on both sides (gui/task). In this case using the statisticsitem object is a reasonable suggestion but it could be any object.